# Is there a way to trigger autocomplete on every key press?

Tags: bash, terminal, kde

I use autocomplete a lot. I found that I was usually using bash in the following fashion:
**To get to ./pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/weakref.py**

- Press ./
- Hit pye, press <kbd>tab</kbd> (terminal autocompletes to pyenv)
- Hit /, press v, press <kbd>tab</kbd> (terminal autocompletes to versions)
- Hit <kbd>3</kbd>. Hit <kbd>tab</kbd>. Terminal completes to `3.`, because there are a lot of pyenv versions. Hit 5, then <kbd>tab</kbd> again.

And so on until I get to my destination.

However, this can be automated. Since terminal doesn't do anything if there are multiple versions of the same name, we can effectively automate pressing tab **on every single key press**.

So every time, if there exists a direct choice to autocomplete what I'm typing, there should be no downfall to automatically completing it.

So the question is: Is there a way to simulate pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> every time I type any key in Terminal?

Comment: You should probably exclude backspace...

Comment: Correct.I'm thinking we could probably just have it for alphabets.

Comment: Organize yourself and use aliases. You won't come far with this approach.

Comment: I think this personally would slow me down - instead of typing quickly and hitting tab various times, I would have to watch each key press and then see if it has auto-complete, then resume after that. What if you want to go to an intermediate destination, like `testdir/` in `/tmp/asdf/testdir/testdoc.txt`?

Comment: @cutrightjm you're right, it could possibly slow me down too, but I feel like I could probably get used to it pretty soon. As for the intermediate destination `testdir`, autocomplete would only complete out the word `testdir/` for you, and not `testdir/testdoc.txt`. So all you'd have to do would be to type <kbd>t</kbd>, and you'd get `testdir/`.

Comment: There you go, another limitation. Since tab is "typed" with every char, how would you change into "./foo/", if there is a "./foo/bar/and/much/longer/" with no other dirs matching the path. You would have to "travel back". This is exactly what i have been trying to tell you. All ppl understand, but ... NM, lets wait for more "ideas" :p

Comment: But the default behaviour of tab does not autocomplete your input to `./foo/bar/and/much/longer/` when you press tab, it only autocompletes to `./foo`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you prefer to use bash by default, but I use zsh and I use an autocomplete feature using this zsh plugin: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions

And it works by autocompleting using your commands history.

Comment: I'm open to trying zsh! Does the autocomplete work the way I'm intending it to?

Comment: Yes, you don't have to type `tab` for every suggestion, as it will show you automatically the best match after each key press. Take a look at the video, and how the describe it __"As you type commands, you will see a completion offered after the cursor in a muted gray color."__
As I said it autocompletes, not on the available commands or in your case available python versions, but uses your command history to give you full command suggestions. I find it extremely useful specially for running commands that I used before, or that I use often

Comment: It does come pretty close to what I'm looking for, but it's not what I want. It's not a generalized solution. I won't always have the directory typed up in my history.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear what you want, but there are several issues.

First of all, the Bash mechanism which triggers the completition is triggered by tab. There might be a mapping able to enter a tab everytime a character is pressed. But this would do so in every other place. The same goes for any script you could "hack". The second problem is CPU usage. If you were to type a lot of commands, everytime a completition would be triggered. Depending on what is to be completed, it may hang shortly.

This desire is absolutely bad practice. Erase it from your memory. Establish a better hierarchie so you can utilise the feature better.

PS
I forgot to mention the mal-function. Imagine all the other things like Xk commands, aliases, functions and parameters. Everytime you time your shell tries to guess filenames. It will become inoperable. You didn't think your idea through.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105287/discussion-on-answer-by-wgrm-is-there-a-way-to-trigger-autocomplete-on-every-key).